# Has some styling changed to produce weird recursive effects?

Tags: bug, user-interface, top-bar

I was on the review/Tools tabs today, and across all the sites where I'm 10k (or 2k as appropriate) they started out ok and then became surreal, with the black notification bar repeating further down the page.

[image: tools tab in IE]

I promptly tried another browser (FF) and though it started out ok, after a while it started happening there too.

[image: tools tab in FF]

It's also happening on the site-picking dropdown, and I use that constantly (unlike /tools) so this must be a recent change.

[image: site dropdown in IE]

F12 in FF gives me:

```
Use of getPreventDefault() is deprecated.  Use defaultPrevented instead. jquery.min.js:3
TypeError: el.closest(...).find(...).addSpinner is not a function jquery.min.js line 2 > eval:73
TypeError: el.closest(...).find(...).addSpinner is not a function tools:165
TypeError: StackExchange.realtime is undefined full.en.js:1
```

and now trying it in Chrome has led me to "There are an unusual number of requests coming from this IP address" and that browser can't use any sites (though this one can... which is strange.)

It is definitely related to that spinner. Some  . . . animation is supposed to appear while the sections are loading. The page looks ok at first, then the entire page appears where the . . . should be.

Comment: I cannot actually reproduce this.

Comment: try expanding and closing some sections and moving around from subtab to subtab. I've actually rebooted and am still getting it.

Comment: I tried expanding and collapsing; I'll move around some more.

Comment: On which URL? Also, which browser extensions do you have?

Comment: Can you introspect the AJAX responses in the developer tools of your browser? I suspect that those AJAX results are trying to tell you an error message. I certainly don't see the issue on my side.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/tools http://travel.stackexchange.com/tools etc. No plugins, and happens in both IE and FF. I'm on Windows 8.1

Comment: no-repro here .

Comment: @MartijnPieters added F12 output. Have screen shot if it helps.

Comment: Try ctrl+f5. Could be outdated javascript

Comment: @KateGregory: that's just the console warning. The developer tools include a network tab where you can capture and introspect all responses, including AJAX (XHR) responses.

Comment: @KateGregory: see [How can I filter XHR requests by name in Chrome developer tools / Firebug](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9644098) and [debug XHR in chrome browser](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1535462) for examples.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Ctrl F then XHR gets me "phrase not found"

Comment: @JanDvorak plenty of Ctrl F5, it's my first thing to try

Comment: @KateGregory: is this Internet Explorer? There is a Network tab there as well. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ie/dn255004(v=vs.85).aspx for example.

Comment: repeated on IE, same spinner error in Debugging tab, Networking tab just hangs there

Comment: Can't reproduce, but the symptoms suggest that a proxy between you and the SE servers may be mangling the AJAX requests. Does this also happen over HTTPS? If not, a broken proxy is indeed the most likely culprit.